# overloaded methods

Tags: javascript, overloading

```
function Activity() {

this.LoadFile = function (path, targetElement) {

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            targetElement.html(data);
        }

    });
};

this.LoadFile = function (path, targetElement, onSuccess) {

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            targetElement.html(data);
            onSuccess(data);
        }

    });
};
```

}

If i try to pass 2 arguments, i get `onSuccess is not a function` so i suppose this isnt working. Is it possible to use overloads in javascipt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of directly specifying overloaded methods as such in JS.

There are *many* workarounds.

In your case, you can define the function with 3 parameters:

```
function (path, targetElement, onSuccess)
```

and if the function is called with only 2 parameters, `onSuccess` will be `undefined`:

```
function (data) {
  targetElement.html(data);
  if (onSuccess) {
    onSuccess(data);
  }
}
```

<sub>You may want to look at [`jQuery.Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) for handling event callbacks, although your function could be rewritten using [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).</sub>

---

For programmers coming from the Java/C# world of overloading <del>learn the JavaScript way</del> you can use a structure like this (*not recommended*, it's simply an example for familiarity):

```
function foo() {
  var fns = {};
  fns[0] = function () {
    //no params
  };
  fns[1] = function () {
    //1 param
  };
  fns[2] = function () {
    //2 params
  };
  fns[arguments.length]();
}
```

to provide separate functions for each "overload", however it's not very flexible and **symptomatic of a poorly planned function**.

---

Oftentimes rather than using a large set of parameters, a single `options` parameter will be used to contain the available parameters:

```
function foo(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({}, foo.defaultSettings, options);
  //do stuff with settings
}
foo.defaultSettings = {
  bar: 'baz',
  fizz: 'buzz'
}
```

Comment: Maybe its better to pass one argument as an object, containing different number of arguments...

Comment: That recommended structure is simply stupid. Tell them to stop doing it wrong and learn javascript

Comment: @Raynos, i never recommended that structure. I was trying to make a point about it. It's ridiculous hence the "symptomatic of a poorly planned function". I guess i wasn't clear enough, so I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Javascript does not support method overloading.

Instead, you can make a single method that takes all three parameters, then check inside the method whether the third parameter was actually passed.  (all Javascript function parameters are optional)

Comment: @Johan: Yes; treat the parameter as optional.

Answer (score 0):

There is still another way to go. Don't give any parameters in the function definition and then examine the `arguments` array(). You can even examine the types of the parameters given, to branch inside your function. The example below will alert `# 1 #` and `Num(2)`

```
/** 
 * Usage
 * example(number param1) 
 * example(string, number)
 */
function example() { // no parameters
    if (arguments.length == 1 && typeof arguments[0] == 'number') {
        alert(' # ' + arguments[0] + ' # ')
    }
    if (arguments.length == 2 && typeof arguments[0] == 'string' && typeof arguments[1] == 'number') {
        alert(arguments[0] + '(' + arguments[1] + ')')
    }

}
example(1);
example('Num', 2)
```